# Blockcypher - Can't call contract method

Tags: tokens, external-api

I'm trying to send erc20 token using the Blockcypher Ethereum API.
specifically the "Call Contract Method"

but I keep getting

```
{"error": "Error calling contract: Missing contract or ABI for 1f342fb495cf6947b2d0db341ab5813042aad66f.."}
```

this is the api call I'm using

> curl -sd  '{"private": "myprivatekey", "gas_limit":80000, "addresses": "addressimsendingto", "value": 500,"abi": "[{\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"name\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_spender\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"approve\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"totalSupply\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_from\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_to\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"transferFrom\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"decimals\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint8\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"enableTokenTransfer\",\"outputs\": [],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"burn\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\" } ],\"name\":\"balanceOf\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"TransferAllowed\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_from\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"burnFrom\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"symbol\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_to\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"transfer\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\" } ],\"name\":\"frozenAccount\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"_spender\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"_value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" }, {\"name\":\"_extraData\",\"type\":\"bytes\" } ],\"name\":\"approveAndCall\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"success\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": true,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\" } ],\"name\":\"allowance\",\"outputs\": [ {\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [],\"name\":\"disableTokenTransfer\",\"outputs\": [],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"target\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"name\":\"freeze\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"name\":\"freezeAccount\",\"outputs\": [],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"constant\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\" } ],\"name\":\"transferOwnership\",\"outputs\": [],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\" }, {\"inputs\": [ {\"name\":\"initialSupply\",\"type\":\"uint256\",\"index\": 0,\"typeShort\":\"uint\",\"bits\":\"256\",\"displayName\":\"initial Supply\",\"template\":\"elements_input_uint\",\"value\":\"1000000\" }, {\"name\":\"tokenName\",\"type\":\"string\",\"index\": 1,\"typeShort\":\"string\",\"bits\":\"\",\"displayName\":\"token Name\",\"template\":\"elements_input_string\",\"value\":\"JST\" }, {\"name\":\"tokenSymbol\",\"type\":\"string\",\"index\": 2,\"typeShort\":\"string\",\"bits\":\"\",\"displayName\":\"token Symbol\",\"template\":\"elements_input_string\",\"value\":\"JST\" } ],\"payable\": false,\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"constructor\" }, {\"anonymous\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"target\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"frozen\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"name\":\"FrozenFunds\",\"type\":\"event\" }, {\"anonymous\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"name\":\"TransferEnabled\",\"type\":\"event\" }, {\"anonymous\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\" } ],\"name\":\"TransferDisabled\",\"type\":\"event\" }, {\"anonymous\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"indexed\": true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"indexed\": true,\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\" }, {\"anonymous\": false,\"inputs\": [ {\"indexed\": true,\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\" }, {\"indexed\": false,\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\" } ],\"name\":\"Burn\",\"type\":\"event\"}]"}' -s https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/contracts/1f342fb495cf6947b2d0db341ab5813042aad66f/transfer?token=myblockcyphertoken

the ABI is from the contract's admin page in Mist, plus the formatting for the BlockCypher api (it doesn't work without the formatting neither...)

can anyone pin point me to a right direction?

this has been bugging the hell outta me for a while now...

Thank you in advance.